# Excel - Finding Max value in a column

Tags: excel, max

I have an Summary sheet set up data set up as follows-

```
         Cat A  Cat B  Cat C  Cat D  
Name 1       0      0      0      0  
Name 2       2      3      2      2  
Name 3       2      2      2      2  
Name 4       3      2      2      3  
Name 5       2      3      2      3
```

I also then have separate tabs for each of Name1 through to Name 5.

The summary sheet contains the maximum values for each category from each tab. So the Cell at Cat A Name 1 should show the maximum value on Sheet(Name1) in the Cat A column.

So far so good. However each tab may not contain the same categories, so therefore I would like teh summary sheet to check the maximum value in each column by doing a search on the Cat name.

So far I have this-

```
=MATCH(Overview!S$1,Name1!$C$1:$V$1,0)
```

Which returns the column number with the right Category, in this case 13. So I can find the right column. What I am struggling with is to now find the maximum value in the column.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

IAssuming your search range goes to row 1000:

```
=MAX(INDEX(Name1!$C$2:$V$1000,0,MATCH(Overview!S$1,Name1!$C$1:$V$1,0)))
```

The 0 Row argument in Index means to select the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

The Offset function is your key here.

After you've got the value from the match, you can pass it to the offset to get the correct column.

So, for example, you probably want something like:

```
=Max(Name1!$C1:$C2000)
```

But you don't know whether you should use the C column or the D column or whatever, in this case, it was 13, so is that the P column? (c=3, the match was 13 so 3+13 = 16 = P?), so I think you want something like this:

```
=Max(Offset(Name1!$C$1:$C$2000, 0, [result of your match expression] - 1))
```

Here's an example of what I think you want in GoogleDocs:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai45AJPc2AWMdGRlZXNIdlZBaHJxc01qVlJWa1N1WXc

Comment: Hi. I tried this but could not get it to work. I just got a blank result. The data on the Name1 tab is in the range C1:V8 so i put that in in place of your $C$1:$C$2000 and put $C$1:$C$8.  I tried to split the formula up and just put the offset part using =OFFSET(NAME1!$C$1:$C$8,13,0) and got #Value error

Comment: So, you do a match to determine which column, and in this case you want column P? So you would want this to effectively compute `Max(Name1!P1:P8)`? Or maybe you want `Max(Name1!P2:P8)`?

Comment: Here, I made what I think you want on GoogleDocs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai45AJPc2AWMdGRlZXNIdlZBaHJxc01qVlJWa1N1WXc

Comment: I did have a bug in that I was swapping row and column on offset.

Comment: One thing to note is that Match is 1 based, whereas Offset is 0-based, so I'd expect an off-by-one-column error with this solution.  In other words, if the Match returns the first column, the Offset will be one column over,  Also, Offset is volatile, so is less efficient than Index.  Generally, I use Index and Match together in these situations.  (Index is also 1-based.)

Comment: Yes, I also fixed that off by one error in the google doc, but forgot to update the answer.

Comment: @DougGlancy, yeah, I haven't done much perf testing, I have no idea which is more efficient.