# How to find maximum value from an excel column?

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I have values like below in excel sheet.

```
ID
12_001
12_008
12_010
```

13_001

How to find max of these values. I need the result as '13_001'. Can anybody help me?

I tried like this

```
string ExcelConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + Filepath + " ; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";
OleDbDataAdapter Id = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [Sheet1$A2:A4]", ExcelConnection);
DataSet id = new DataSet();
Id.Fill(id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can get the desired output by treating the strings as text, sorting them alphabetically in descending order and then retrieving the first record from column ID.

Below code should do it:

```
        string ExcelConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + Filepath + " ; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";
        string Command = "SELECT ID FROM [Sheet1$]";

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnection);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(Command, conn);
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);


                DataSet id = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(id);

                DataTable idtable = id.Tables[0];
                idtable.DefaultView.Sort = idtable.Columns[0].ColumnName + " " + "DESC";
                idtable = idtable.DefaultView.ToTable();
                Console.WriteLine(idtable.Rows[0][0]);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
you can use the range if u need 

    range rng = new range; 
int64  dblMax =0; rng = Range("a1", Range("a65536").End(xlUp)) ;
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) ;
return dblMax + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can send function you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506771/excel-finding-max-value-in-a-column):

```
=MAX(INDEX(Name1!$C$2:$V$2000,0,MATCH(Overview!S$1,ID!$C$1:$V$1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This at best can be done through a macro. In the below listing I have different values in Range A1:A10 like:
12_001
56_021
89_001
10_002
41_005
36_021
95_002
25_025
32-015
85-002
I am extracting the maximum value thro the following code. The maximum value is displayed in a Message Box:

```
For i = 1 To 10
If Val(Left(Cells(i, 1), 2)) > Max Then
Max = Val(Left(Cells(i, 1), 2))
Strg = Max & Right(Cells(i, 1), Len(Cells(i, 1)) - 2)
End If
Next
MsgBox Strg
```